# Installing chrome driver with version docker

Tags: docker, containers, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I have one docker file which setup chromium browser and chromium driver using alpine base image. Currently it is setting up latest version?
Is there any way to specify version here?

```
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache bash \
    alsa-lib \
    at-spi2-atk \
    atk \
    cairo \
    cups-libs \
    dbus-libs \
    eudev-libs \
    expat \
    flac \
    gdk-pixbuf \
    glib \
    libgcc \
    libjpeg-turbo \
    libpng \
    libwebp \
    libx11 \
    libxcomposite \
    libxdamage \
    libxext \
    libxfixes \
    tzdata \
    libexif \
    udev \
    xvfb \
    zlib-dev \
    chromium \
    chromium-chromedriver
```

Comment: Have a look on [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1055060/how-to-install-a-specific-package-version-in-alpine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible. In theory you could use something like

```
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache bash \
    alsa-lib \
    at-spi2-atk \
    atk \
    cairo \
    cups-libs \
    dbus-libs \
    eudev-libs \
    expat \
    flac \
    gdk-pixbuf \
    glib \
    libgcc \
    libjpeg-turbo \
    libpng \
    libwebp \
    libx11 \
    libxcomposite \
    libxdamage \
    libxext \
    libxfixes \
    tzdata \
    libexif \
    udev \
    xvfb \
    zlib-dev \
    chromium=1.0.154.65 \
    chromium-chromedriver=1.0.154.65
```

But that fails with:

```
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  chromium-72.0.3626.121-r0:
    breaks: world[chromium=1.0.154.65]
  chromium-chromedriver-72.0.3626.121-r0:
    breaks: world[chromium-chromedriver=1.0.154.65]
```

The reason is that old packages are dropped when alpine is updated. So if you want to use specific version of chromium you have to look at https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=chromium&branch=v3.7 and search for the alpine version that includes the chromium version that you need and then you need to use that version of alpine as your base image (for example `FROM alpine:3.7` if you want chromium in version 61.0.3163.100-r0). Another solution would be to create an own mirror.

If you need more infos I can recommend [this blog post](https://medium.com/@stschindler/the-problem-with-docker-and-alpines-package-pinning-18346593e891)